# Comparing two multi-dimensional arrays, but leaving room for error margin

Tags: php, arrays

I have two arrays, that look like this:

```
Array
(
    [car] => Array
        (
            [color] => green
            [miles] => 1.2
            [consumption] => 5.0245
            [doors] => 3
            ...
        )

    [cat] => Array
        (
            [name] => kitty
            [color] => ginger
            ...
        )

    [children] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [assets] => Array
                        (
                            [smartphone] => 500.14
                            [clothes] => 1351.4
                            ...
                        )

                    [name] => john
                    [age] => 16
                    [length] => 1.83045
                    ...
                    [something_else] => Array
                        (
                            [foo] => 1.75141
                            [bar] => something here
                            ...
                        )
                ),
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [assets] => Array
                        (
                            [smartphone] => 300.1
                            [clothes] => 598.1154
                            ...
                        )

                    [name] => alice
                    [age] => 12
                    [length] => 1.7045
                    ...
                    [something_else] => Array
                        (
                            [foo] => 8.0245
                            [bar] => something here too
                            ...
                        )
                ),
            ...
        )

    [house] => Array
        (
            [style] => urban
            [bathrooms] => 1
            [electricity_consumption] => 18.420154
            ...
        )

    [last_one] => another string
)
```

Both arrays contain the same keys in every dimension, but not necessarily in the same order. For example: `children` might come before `cat`, or `doors` in the `cat`-dimension might come before `color` etc. The number of `children` is variable, but it's always at least 1, and both arrays will always contain the same amount of `children`.

I need to compare if those to arrays contain the same information, as in: the values must be the same.
I used to simply use `if($array1!=$array2){return false;}` and it worked great.

Now, there's a need to expand this a little: I want to compare it, but leave room for a 1% error margin in the numbers. For example, if the value for [car][consumption] in the first array is 5.0245, and in the second one 5.0241, the result should be that the arrays are "the same".

I guess I need to loop through every single value, figure out if it's a number or not, compare the value leaving room for error, and return `false` the moment one of these values is more than 1% different.

I was trying something like:

```
   foreach ($array1 as $key => $value)
    {
        if(is_array($value))
        {
            foreach($value as $key2 => $value2)
            {
                if(is_array($value2))
                {
```

but I have difficulties figuring out how to do the comparing then... Also, this approach seems prone to bugs and not really future proof (for example if extra dimensions should exist in the future).

Does anyone know a more convenient way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```php
function compareWithMargin($a, $b) {
  if (is_array($a) || is_array($b)) { // if array, compare in depth
    if (!is_array($a) || !is_array($b)) return false; // if another is not an array - then bad
    if (count($a) != count($b)) return false; // not equal length
    foreach ($a as $k => $v) {
      if (!array_key_exists($k, $b)) return false; // no such a key in another array
      if (!compareWithMargin($v, $b[$k])) return false; // comparison failed
    }   
    return true; // good
  } elseif (is_numeric($a) && is_numeric($b)) {
    // compare with margin
    return (abs($a - $b) <= ((abs($a) + abs($b)) * 0.005)); // difference is less than 1% of half of the sum
  } else {
    return $a == $b; // usual comparison
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Seems to work great! One thing I noticed though is that it's not exactly 1% margin. For example, if one value is 0.3 and the other value is 0.3004, the function returns `true`. Not a biggy for my use case, but still wanted to mention it for other people.

Comment: Thats because 0.0004 difference is less than 0.003 (3% of 0.3)